# Property of sum $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}}{1+\exp{((2k+1)\pi)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, special-functions

Is it true that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{align}f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}}{1+\exp{((2k+1)\pi)}}\end{align}
is always rational.
I have calculated via Mathematica, which says \begin{align}f(0)=\frac{1}{24},f(1)=\frac{31}{504},f(2)=\frac{511}{264},f(3)=\frac{8191}{24}\end{align}
But I couldn't find the pattern or formula behind these numbers, Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the origin of this sum?

Comment: @vesszabo Emm..My friend asked me via forum, I still wonder what was his intention to study this series.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This series appears in Apostol's book "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory" p.25 according to [(8) from MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Series.html) with the result (if your series starts with $k=0$) :
$$f(n)=\frac {2^{4n+1}-1}{8n+4}\,B_{4n+2}$$
with $B_n$ a [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

UPDATE: Apostol's book may be consulted [here](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14008594/Apostol-T-Modular-Functions-and-Dirichlet-Series-in-Number-Theory-0387971270) and the theorem $13.17$ is the proof of the [classical relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) between $\zeta(2n)$ and $B_{2n}$.

Comment: Great!(+2) if it was possible.

Comment: @vesszabo: Glad you liked it! For other results of this kind see ['zeta constant'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_constant) and Vepstas' paper ['On Plouffe's Ramanujan Identities'](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0609775).

Comment: I know Bernoulli numbers and it was suspicious that the sum has relation with B numbers (because in the denominator there is exp function), but I couldn't find it. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an  approach using Mellin transforms to  enrich the collection
of solutions. We seek to evaluate (assuming that we start the original
series at $k=0$ as observed above)

$$f(n) = \sum_{k\ge 1}
\frac{(2k-1)^{4n+1}}{1+\exp((2k-1)\pi)},$$
this one  started at $k=1$ which  corresponds to $k=0$  in the problem
statement.

There is a harmonic sum here which we now evaluate by Mellin transform
inversion.

Introduce $$S(x) = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} 
\frac{((2k-1)x)^{4n+1}}{1+\exp((2k-1)\pi x)}$$
so that we are interested in $S(1).$

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have that 
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = 2k-1 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\pi x)}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+\exp(\pi x)} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(-\pi x)}{1+\exp(-\pi x)} x^{s-1} dx
\\= \int_0^\infty 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^{q-1} e^{-\pi q x} \right) x^{s-1} dx
= \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^{q-1} 
\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi q x} x^{s-1} dx
\\= \frac{1}{\pi^s} \Gamma(s) \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{q-1}}{q^s}
= \frac{1}{\pi^s} 
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^s}\right)\Gamma(s) \zeta(s).$$

The series that we have used here converges absolutely for $x$ in the integration limits.

It  follows that  the Mellin  transform $Q(s)$  of the  harmonic sum
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{1}{\pi^{s+4n+1}} 
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{s+4n+1}}\right)\Gamma(s+4n+1) \zeta(s+4n+1)
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^s} \right) \zeta(s)
\\ \text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^s}
= \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^s} \right) \zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

To see this note that the base function of the sum is
$$\frac{x^{4n+1}}{1+\exp(\pi x)} .$$

The  Mellin  inversion  integral  for  $Q(s)$  is  $$\frac{1}{2\pi  i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}  Q(s)/x^s ds$$  which we  evaluate by
shifting it to the left for  an expansion about zero.

As it turns out we only need the contribution from the pole at $s=1.$

We have that
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=1\right)
= \frac{1}{\pi^{4n+2}}
\left(1-\frac{2}{2^{4n+2}}\right)
\times (4n+1)! \times
\zeta(4n+2)\times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{x}
\\= \frac{1}{\pi^{4n+2}}
\frac{2^{4n+2}-2}{2^{4n+2}}
\times (4n+1)! \times
\frac{(-1)^{(2n+1)+1} B_{4n+2} (2\pi)^{4n+2}}{2\times (4n+2)!}
\times \frac{1}{2}  \times \frac{1}{x}
\\ = (2^{4n+1}-1)\frac{B_{4n+2}}{8n+4}  \times \frac{1}{x}.$$

This almost concludes  the evaluation the result being  the residue we
just computed because we can show that $Q(s)/x^s$ with $x=1$ is odd on
the  line $\Re(s) =  -2n$ so  that it  vanishes and  if we  stop after
shifting to  that line the  Mellin inversion integral that  we started
with is equal to the contribution from the pole at $s=1.$

To see this put $s=-2n+it$ to obtain
$$\frac{1}{\pi^{2n+1+it}} 
\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{2n+1+it}}\right)\Gamma(2n+1+it) \zeta(2n+1+it)
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{-2n+it}} \right) \zeta(-2n+it)$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{\pi^{2n+1+it}} 
\frac{2^{2n+1+it}-2}{2^{2n+1+it}} \Gamma(2n+1+it) \zeta(2n+1+it)
\frac{2^{-2n+it}-1}{2^{-2n+it}} \zeta(-2n+it)$$

Now use  the functional equation of  the Riemann Zeta  function in the
following form:
$$\zeta(1-s) = \frac{2}{2^s\pi^s} 
\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
to transform the above into
$$(2^{2n+1+it}-2)
\times \frac{\zeta(1-(2n+1+it))}{2\cos(\pi(2n+1+it)/2)}
\frac{2^{-2n+it}-1}{2^{-2n+it}} \zeta(-2n+it)$$
which is
$$(2^{2n+it}-1)
\times \frac{\zeta(-2n-it))}{\cos(\pi it + \pi(2n+1)/2)}
(1-2^{2n-it}) \zeta(-2n+it)$$
which we finally rewrite as
$$(2^{2n+it}-1) (1-2^{2n-it})
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sin(\pi it/2)}
\zeta(-2n+it)\zeta(-2n-it)$$
or
$$(1-2^{2n+it}) (1-2^{2n-it})
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sin(\pi it/2)}
\zeta(-2n+it)\zeta(-2n-it).$$

Among this product of five terms the first two taken together are even
as are the  last two zeta function terms. The middle  sine term is odd
in $t$, so  the entire product is  odd in $t$ and we  are done, having
obtained the answer
$$(2^{4n+1}-1)\frac{B_{4n+2}}{8n+4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate the function $$g(z) = \frac{z^{4n+1}e^{iz}}{\cosh(z) + \cos(z)} $$ around the  contour $[-\sqrt{2} \pi N, \sqrt{2} \pi N] \cup \sqrt{2} \pi Ne^{i[0, \pi]}, $ where $N$ is a positive integer.

This is the same approach that I used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4456955/16033) to show the $n=0$ case  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{e^{(2k+1)\pi }+1} = \frac{1}{24}.$$

The integral vanishes on the semicircle as $N \to \infty$ through the positive integers for the same reasons explained in my previous answer.

So we have

$$ \begin{align} &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4n+1}e^{ix}}{\cosh(x) + \cos(x)} \, \mathrm dx \\&= 2 \pi i \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Res} \left[g(z), \frac{(2k+1) \pi (1+i)}{2} \right] + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Res} \left[g(z),  \frac{(2k+1) \pi (-1+i)}{2} \right]\right)  \\ &= 2 \pi i \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim_{z \to  \frac{(2k+1) \pi (1+i)}{2}  }\frac{z^{4n+1}e^{iz}}{\sinh(z) - \sin(z)} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim_{z \to \frac{(2k+1) \pi (-1+i)}{2}  }\frac{z^{4n+1}e^{iz}}{\sinh(z) - \sin(z)} \right) \\ &= \small 2 \pi i \left( \frac{\pi }{2} \right)^{4n+1} (-1)^{n} 2^{2n} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}(1+i) i e^{-(2k+1) \pi /2}}{(-1+i)\cosh \left(\frac{(2k+1) \pi }{2} \right)} \color{red}{-} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}(-1+i) i e^{-(2k+1) \pi /2}}{ (1+i) \cosh \left(\frac{(2k+1) \pi }{2} \right)}\right) \\&= 2 \pi i \left( \frac{\pi }{2} \right)^{4n+1} (-1)^{n} 2^{2n} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}e^{-(2k+1) \pi/2}}{\cosh \left(\frac{(2k+1) \pi }{2}\right)}+ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}e^{-(2k+1) \pi/2}}{\cosh \left(\frac{(2k+1) \pi }{2}\right)} \right)  \\ &= \frac{(-1)^{n}\pi^{4n+2}}{2^{2n-1}} i  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1} e^{- (2k+1) \pi /2}}{\cosh \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi }{2} \right)}  \\ &=   \frac{(-1)^{n}\pi^{4n+2}}{2^{2n-2}} i   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}}  {e^{(2k+1)\pi }+1}. \end{align} $$

Then equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we have

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)^{4n+1}}{e^{(2k+1)\pi}+1} &= \frac
{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n-2}}{\pi^{4n+2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4n+1} \sin(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \, \mathrm dx \\& = \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n-1}}{\pi^{4n+2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4n+1} \sin(x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos(x)} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n}}{\pi^{4n+2}} \Im \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{4n+1} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m-1} e^{(-1+i)mx} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n}}{\pi^{4n+2}} \Im \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{4n+1} e^{(-1+i)mx} \, \mathrm dx \\ &\overset{\spadesuit}{=} \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{2n}}{\pi^{4n+2}} \Im \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m-1} \frac{(4n+1)!}{\left((1-i)m\right)^{4n+2}} \\ &= \frac{(4n+1)!}{2 \pi^{4n+2}} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m^{4n+2}} \\ &= \frac{(4n+1)!}{2 \pi^{4n+2}} \eta(4n+2) \\ &\overset{\clubsuit}{=} \frac{(4n+1)!}{2 \pi^{4n+2}} \frac{B_{4n+2} \pi^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!} \left(2^{4n+1}-1 \right) \\ &= \frac{B_{4n+2}}{8n+4} \left(2^{4n+1}-1 \right). \end{align}$$

---

$\spadesuit$ $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a}e^{-sx} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{s^{a+1}}, \quad (a >-1, \ \Re(s) >0) $

$\clubsuit$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Particular_values