# Find the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate this infinite sum? 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n-1}$$

Comment: Why the expression appears so small? How can I enlarge that? : (

Comment: use \displaystyle

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this one appears in one volume of Ramanujan's notebook. (Chris)

Comment: $1.606695152415291$

Comment: I saw this sum before

Comment: Is there a closed form?

Comment: No I remember that the constant was called  E

Comment: How about if we change the infinity with k?

Comment: The numerators and denominators of the partial sums are OEIS sequences A087689 and A087690.

Comment: Not an answer, but it is easy to convert the formula to:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\tau(m)}{2^m}$$

where $\tau(m)$ is the number of distinct divisors of $m$.

Comment: I made a comment as an answer, see below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanna see this:

*Ramanujan’s Notebooks Part I*

[Click me and try Entry $14$ (ii) / pag 146 where you set $x=\ln2$](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan%27s%20Notebooks%20I.pdf)

Chris.

Comment: I want to write out that particular equation just because it's so . . . out there:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{1}{e^{kx}-1}=\frac{\gamma}{x}-\frac{\log x}{x}+\frac{1}{4}-\sum_{1 \le k \le n}\frac{B^2_{2k}x^{2k-1}}{(2k)(2k)!}+R_n,
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, $B_{2k}$ are the conventionally defined Bernoulli numbers, $x>0$, $n\ge 1$, and $R_n$ is a constant bounded by the inequality
$$
|R_n|\le \frac{|B_{2n}B_{2n+2}|x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6} \right).
$$
For our case, let $x=\ln 2$ as Chris's sister stated.

Comment: @Limitless: thank you for the details provided! (+1)

Comment: The following [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/a-new-formula-for-aperys-constant-and-other-zetas) shows how to evaluate this type of sum by inverting Mellin transforms.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. I found it. It is called the Erdős-Borwein Constant.

> $$E=\sum_{n\in Z^+}\frac{1}{2^n-1}$$

Check http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html

According to the page, Erdős showed that it is irrational.

Comment: I almost see in each step in the link a possible nice question to ask. :D (+1)

Comment: Is it known whether the *Erdos-Borwein  Constant* is transcendental or not?

Comment: I have no idea. I guess no.

Comment: @Rustyn: Please use [markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for non-mathematical things like italics and bold in normal text. I've edited your comment.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ok, I will in the future.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^k-\frac{1}{r}}=\frac{r}{\log (q)} \left(\psi _q^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\log (r)}{\log (q)}\right)-\psi _q^{(0)}\left(n+1-\frac{\log (r)}{\log (q)}\right)\right)
$$

In trying to get Mathematica to solve the series, I eventually found the preceding form which assumes $0<q<1$. If we take $q=1/2$, $r=1$ and let n approach infinity, we get the same solution that Amr references. The partial sum solution utilizes the [function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html), $\psi _q^{(n)}(z)$.

$$
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{1}{\log (1/2)}\left(\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}(1)-\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}(n+1)\right)=1+\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}(1)}{\log (1/2)}=E
$$

Answer (score 0):

*(This is not meant as an answer but it is too long for the comment.box)*

Since you mentioned interest in variations of the problem: here is a text, in which L. Euler discussed that sum:

> "Consideratio quarumdam serierum quae singularibus proprietatibus sunt
>   praeditae"  (“Consideration of some series which are distinguished by
>   special properties”)
>   L. Euler Eneström-index E190.

You can find it online.

---

A further discussion of this by Prof. Ed Sandifer, where he sheds light on a very interesting discussion about a "false series for the logarithm" at which that constant pops up (and which actually had pointed me originally to L.Euler's article):

> A false logarithm series (Discussion of E190)
>   Ed. Sandifer in: "How Euler did it" Dec 2007
>   http://www.maa.org/editorial/euler/How%20Euler%20Did%20It%2050%20false%20log%20series.pdf

---

I've fiddled then with it myself a bit further, maybe you find that [amateurish explorations](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FalseLogarithm.pdf) interesting too. The constant is part of a consideration on page 5.