# Is there an explicit irrational number which is not known to be either algebraic or transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

There are many numbers which are not able to be classified as being rational, algebraic irrational, or transcendental. Is there an explicit number which is known to be irrational but not known to be either algebraic or transcendental?

Comment: I would think numbers like $.121121112\dots$ would do the job, no?  Liouville doesn't obviously give us transcendence (at least it isn't obvious to me).

Comment: $e+\pi$ or $e\cdot\pi$.

Comment: @studentforever: I don't know that either of those numbers has the indicated property. (Of course at most one of them is rational, but I can't see how that helps here.)

Comment: @lulu I believe that number is known to be transcendental.  It's the sum of a rational number ($\frac19$) and a theta-value at a rational argument that I'm pretty sure is known not to be algebraic.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Ah...let's see. Certainly a mistake to use only $1's$...makes it too easy to subtract $\frac 19$.   Is my example better if we cycle through the digits?   $.192293339\dots$?  Surely there's a simple way to write a non-periodic decimal to which we can't apply Liouville or the like...

Comment: Erdős proved that the Erdős–Borwein constant $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} = 1.60669\!\ldots$ is irrational, and to my knowledge whether it's algebraic remains open; the comments below this old answer suggest that's the case: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/266638/155629 . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Borwein_constant

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe the best-known example is *[Apery's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant)*,
$$\zeta(3) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3} = 1.20205\!\ldots ,$$
which Apery proved was irrational a few decades ago; this result is known as *Apery's Theorem*.

By contrast, $\zeta(2) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ has value $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which is transcendental because $\pi$ is.

> Apéry, Roger (1979), *Irrationalité de $\zeta(2)$ et $\zeta(3)$*, Astérisque **(61)**, 11–13.

Comment: And $\zeta(2n+1)$ in general for $n\geq 1$ is not known either, I think.

Comment: @Jake I think that's true, but I don't think it's known for any odd $m > 3$ whether $\zeta(m)$ is even rational. It is known, perhaps a little oddly, that at least one of the first four such numbers is irrational. (See Zudilin, Wadim (2001), *One of the numbers $\zeta(5)$, $\zeta(7)$, $\zeta(9)$, $\zeta(11)$ is irrational*, Russ. Math. Surv. 56 **(4)**, 774–776.)

Comment: Ah yes. I was being hasty. Thank you :)

Comment: Wow, I thought I knew the Greek symbols by sight, but I had to look up that weird salamander-looking thing to find out it's a lower-case Zeta.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: in maths undergrad terms that's "other squiggle", with "squiggle" being $\xi$.

Comment: Shouldn't the summation in Riemann's Zeta function start at n=1?

Comment: @ViníciusBarros Yes, of course, thanks for pointing it out (I've fixed the typo).

Answer (score 7):

The most famous have been answered. Let us be a little  less constructive. At least one of [$\zeta(5)$, $\zeta(7)$, $\zeta(9)$, $\zeta(11)$](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~wzudilin/zeta5-11$.pdf) is irrational, a result due to V. V. Zudilin, Communications of Moscow Mathematical Society (2001), and their true nature (algebraic and transcendental) seems unknown at the present time. This result improves the irrationality of one of the nine numbers $\zeta(5)$, $\zeta(7)$, $\ldots$ $\zeta(21)$.

Comment: Is it known that these numbers are all irrational?

Comment: @Charles not by me, but at least of them (explicitely) is irrational, and unknown to be algebraic or transcendental. This is why I called my answer non constructive

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Comment: @Charles glad you liked it, pfiou...

Answer (score 4):

$$ \frac{\ln\pi}{\pi}, $$

This example is irrational because $$\frac{\ln\pi}{\pi}=\frac{p}{q} \implies \pi^{q}=\left(e^{\pi}\right)^{p}$$

But this is impossible because [Nesterenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Valentinovich_Nesterenko)
demonstrated that $e^{\pi}$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent.

As far as I know, there is not a demonstration that $\ln(\pi)/\pi$ is transcendental which doesn't invoke the far from proven [Schanuel's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

Another nice example might be $t$ such that $2^t+3^t=6$. This is perfectly explicit despite us not being able to write down $t$ in terms of other constants. It's also nice and constructive in a way that should allow for making more examples. The solution to an exponential integer equation should be [demonstrably irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638633/is-x-irrational-when-2x3x-6?noredirect=1&lq=1) but not necessarily demonstrably transcendental (But again assuming Schanuel's Conjecture [one can make progress](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531815/schanuels-conjecture-implies-no-surprises-on-the-integers-2t3t-1-impl)).

Comment: Great example, Mason!

Comment: ${\ln(\pi)}/{\ln\Gamma(\frac{22}{3})}$ has the same property of being clearly irrational but not necessarily demonstrably transcendental because $\pi$ and $\Gamma(22/3)$ are algebraically independent according to [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). $\{a,b\}$ has transcendence degree $2$ implies $\ln(a) /\ln(b)$ irrational(but not transcendental). The question becomes: Did the theory that allowed for proving $a$, $b$ algebraic also provide an an inroad for proving $\ln a / \ln b$ transcendental.