# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{2u+1}}$ with multiple integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

I am trying to evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{2u+1}}\tag{$u\in\mathbb{N}$}$$ using some results I've got. I know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_0\right)}{k}=\tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\theta_0/2\right)\right)$$ which equals $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi-\theta_0\right)$ whenever $0\leq\theta_0<2\pi.$ I realized that if I integrate both sides from $0$ to $\theta_1$, I get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(k\theta_1\right)-1}{k^{2}}=-\frac{\pi\theta_1}{2}+\frac{\theta_1^{2}}{4}\\\implies\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(k\theta_1\right)}{k^{2}}=\zeta\left(2\right)-\frac{\pi\theta_1}{2}+\frac{\theta_1^{2}}{4}$$ and integrating one more time from $0$ to $\theta_2$ show me that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_2\right)}{k^{3}}=\frac{\theta_2^{3}}{12}-\frac{\pi\theta_2^{2}}{4}+\zeta\left(2\right)\theta_2.$$ I considered integrating the first equation a $n$ number of times, so I could write $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{n}}\cdots\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{1}}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{0}\right)}{k}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{0}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}\right)\cdots\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{n-1}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{n}}\cdots\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{1}}\pi-\theta_{0}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{0}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}\right)\cdots\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{n-1}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{n}^{n}}{n!}-\frac{\theta_{n}^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right)$$ using the well-established zeta function of a even number and somehow extracting the trigonometric sum apart from that mess. Looking at some attempts like $$\int_0^{\theta_1}\frac{\sin(k\theta_0)}{k}\,\mathrm d\theta_0=\frac{-\cos(k\theta_1)}{k^2}+\frac{1}{0!k^2}$$ $$\int_0^{\theta_2}\frac{-\cos(k\theta_1)}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2}\,\mathrm d\theta_1=\frac{-\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^3}+\frac{\theta_2}{1!k^2}$$ $$\int_0^{\theta_3}\frac{-\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^3}+\frac{\theta_2}{1!k^2}\,\mathrm d\theta_2=\frac{\cos(k\theta_3)}{k^4}+\frac{\theta_3^2}{2!k^2}-\frac{1}{0!k^4}$$ $$\int_0^{\theta_4}\frac{\cos(k\theta_3)}{k^4}+\frac{\theta_3^2}{2!k^2}-\frac{1}{0!k^4}\,\mathrm d\theta_3=\frac{\sin(k\theta_4)}{k^5}+\frac{\theta_4^3}{3!k^2}-\frac{\theta_4}{1!k^4}$$ $$\int_0^{\theta_5}\frac{\sin(k\theta_4)}{k^5}+\frac{\theta_4^3}{3!k^2}-\frac{\theta_4}{1!k^4}\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{-\cos(k\theta_5)}{k^6}+\frac{\theta_5^4}{4!k^2}-\frac{\theta_5^2}{2!k^4}+\frac{1}{0!k^6}$$ show some pattern. Which pattern? I conjectured that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{n}}\cdots\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{\theta_{1}}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{0}\right)}{k}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{0}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}\right)\cdots\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{n-1}\right)\\=\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(n\pi/2+k\theta_{n}\right)}{k^{n+1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i+1}\theta^{n+1-2i}_{n}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(n+1-2i)!}$$ which seems quite plausible (otherwise, it wouldn't be a conjecture). This implies $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(n\pi/2+k\theta_{n}\right)}{k^{n+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{n}^{n}}{n!}-\frac{\theta_{n}^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+i}\theta_{n}^{n+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(n+1-2i)!}$$ and, because I am interested in the case $n=2u$, this turns out to be $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(u\pi+k\theta_{n}\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\left(-1\right)^{u}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{2u+1}}\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2u}^{2u}}{(2u+1)!}-\frac{\theta_{2u}^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{2u+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}$$ and, therefore $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{2u+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}.$$ Now, some questions: how do I prove whether my conjecture is right? Is there any cool tricks I can use when dealing with multiple integrations like these? Is there another approach with this series?

**EDIT**

Maybe induction can help me. My own attempt: Assume $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{2u+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}$$ $$=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}.$$ Base case $u=1:$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{3}}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^2}{2}-\frac{\theta^3}{6}\right)+\frac{\theta\zeta(2)}{1}=-\frac{\pi\theta^2}{4}+\frac{\theta^3}{12}+\theta\,\zeta(2)$$
Surprisingly, it is right! Now, I will try to work out the case $u=t+1.$

**SECOND EDIT** As my answer shows, induction can prove that my conjecture was right. Problem solved.

Comment: Holy cow! That looks like *anyone's* worst nightmare...! What about using the exponential function $\,\sin k\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ik\theta}-e^{-ik\theta}\right)\, $ ? I don't know yet what happens, but it looks less dreadful, and since you get the zeta function into the mess I guess you already know some complex analysis, don't you?

Comment: @DonAntonio I have tried it. I don't think it will work because the similar sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(k\theta\right)}{k}=-\log(2) -\log(1-\cos(\theta))$$ is awfully more complicated to integrate.

Comment: In fact, if I could easily integrate this sum, I should be able to "easily" find a formula for $\zeta\left(2n+1\right)$ simply plugging in $\theta=0$. You know what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My own attempt by induction: Assume $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{2u+1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}$$ $$=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}.$$ Base case $u=1$: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{}\right)}{k^{3}}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^2}{2}-\frac{\theta^3}{6}\right)+\frac{\theta\zeta(2)}{1}=-\frac{\pi\theta^2}{4}+\frac{\theta^3}{12}+\theta\,\zeta(2)$$

Now, I will integrate both sides twice. The left hand side:

$$\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta_{0}\right)}{k^{2t+1}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{0}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\theta_2}-\frac{\cos(k\theta_1)}{k^{2t+2}}+\frac{1}{k^{2t+2}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta_1\\=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^{2(t+1)+1}}+\theta_2\,\zeta(2(t+1))$$

The right hand side: $$\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}\\=\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}+\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}$$ The first double integral:
$$\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\left(\frac{\pi\theta^{2u}}{(2u)!}-\frac{\theta^{2u+1}}{\left(2u+1\right)!}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)}}{(2(u+1))!}-\frac{\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1}}{\left(2(u+1)+1\right)!}\right)$$

The second double integral: $$\int_{0}^{\theta_2}\int_{0}^{\theta_1}\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2u+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2u+1-2i)!}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta^{2(u+1)+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2(u+1)+1-2i)!}$$

Putting everything together: $$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^{2(u+1)+1}}+\theta_2\,\zeta(2(u+1))=\frac{\left(-1\right)^u}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)}}{(2(u+1))!}-\frac{\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1}}{\left(2(u+1)+1\right)!}\right)\\+\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+i}\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2(u+1)+1-2i)!}\\\implies\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^{2(u+1)+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+1}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)}}{(2(u+1))!}-\frac{\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1}}{\left(2(u+1)+1\right)!}\right)\\+\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{(u+1)+i}\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2(u+1)+1-2i)!}+\theta_2\,\zeta(2(u+1))\\\implies\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^{2(u+1)+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+1}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)}}{(2(u+1))!}-\frac{\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1}}{\left(2(u+1)+1\right)!}\right)\\+\sum_{i=1}^{u+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{(u+1)+i}\theta_{2}^{2(u+1)+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2(u+1)+1-2i)!}$$ Success, the conjecture is true. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k\theta_2)}{k^{2t+1}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{t}}{2}\left(\frac{\pi\theta_{2}^{2t}}{(2t)!}-\frac{\theta_{2}^{2t+1}}{\left(2t+1\right)!}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{t}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{t+i}\theta_{2}^{2t+1-2i}\zeta\left(2i\right)}{(2t+1-2i)!}$$

Answer (score 6):

It seems  to have escaped attention  that these sums  may be evaluated
using harmonic summation techniques. In  fact we can reduce the amount
of computational effort quite considerably.

To see this, introduce the sum
$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{2p+1}}$$
with $p$ a positive integer and $x$ a real number.

This sum converges absolutely and  it is harmonic and may be evaluated
by inverting its Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{k^{2p+1}}, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \sin x.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \sin x \times x^{s-1} dx.$$

Compute the fundamental strip of  this transform. In a neighborhood of
zero,  $\sin x  \sim x$ and we  need $\Re(s)  > -1$  so  the integral
converges  there.  At  infinity   $\sin  x$  is  bounded  which  gives
convergence  for  $\Re(s-1)<-1$  or   $\Re(s)  <  0.$  Therefore  the
fundamental strip is $\langle -1, 0 \rangle.$

The following series of 
[MSE posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479586/evaluate-int-0-infty-cost-tz-1dt-gammaz-cos-frac-pi-z2)
explains in great detail using a variety of methods why
$$\int_0^\infty e^{\pm ix} x^{s-1} dx
= e^{\pm \pi i s/2} \Gamma(s).$$
This implies that 
$$g^*(s) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(s).$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(s)
\zeta(s+2p+1)
\\ \text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^{2p+1}} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \zeta(s+2p+1)$$
for $\Re(s) > -2p.$

The   Mellin   inversion   integral   here   is   $$\frac{1}{2\pi   i}
\int_{-1/2-i\infty}^{-1/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$  which we evaluate by
shifting it  to the left  for an expansion  about zero. The  choice of
line  was determined  by the  fundamental strip  of $g^*(s)$  which is
completely embedded  in the half-plane of  convergence $\Re(s)>-2p$ of
the sum term.

We  now proceed  to  collect  the contribution  in  residues from  the
poles. The sine  zerm cancels all poles at even  integers of the gamma
function. The trivial zeros of the zeta function term cancel the poles
$s+2p+1 =  -2q$ where $q\ge  1$ i.e. $-2(q+p)-1$  or the poles  at odd
integers  strictly less  than $-2p-1.$  This leaves  the  odd integers
between $-2p-1$ and $-1.$

First, the pole at $s=-2p-1:$
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=-2p-1\right)
= (-1)^{p+1} \frac{(-1)^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}\times -\frac{1}{2} 
\times x^{2p+1} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{(2p+1)!}
\times x^{2p+1}.$$

Second, the pole at $s=-2p$ which  is even, the one exception. This is
a double  pole which  is why  it did not  get canceled.  Combining the
expansion of  the zeta term  with the sine  term about $s=-2p$
leaves  us with  a  factor  of  $(-1)^p\pi/2$ which  we
combine with the gamma function term to obtain
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=-2p\right)
= \frac{\pi}{2} (-1)^p \frac{(-1)^{2p}}{(2p)!} x^{2p}
= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{(-1)^p}{(2p)!} x^{2p}.$$

The contibution from the remaining poles is easy and given by
$$\sum_{q=0}^{p-1} 
\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=-(2q+1)\right)
= \sum_{q=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{q+1} \frac{(-1)^{2q+1}}{(2q+1)!} 
\zeta(2p-2q) x^{2q+1}\\ = 
\sum_{q=0}^{p-1} (-1)^q \frac{\zeta(2p-2q)}{(2q+1)!} x^{2q+1}.$$

Collecting everything into one sum we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{p+1}
\left(\frac{x^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!} - \pi \frac{x^{2p}}{(2p)!}\right)
+ \sum_{q=0}^{p-1} (-1)^q \frac{\zeta(2p-2q)}{(2q+1)!} x^{2q+1}.$$

This is  indeed the same  expansion that we  saw earlier in  the other
posts. It holds for $x\in[0,2\pi).$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. You can write the sum in terms of the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^\left(ik\theta\right)}{k^{2u+1}}-\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^\left(-ik\theta\right)}{k^{2u+1}}=\frac{1}{2i}(\operatorname{Li}_{2u+1}(e^{i\theta})- \operatorname{Li}_{2u+1}(e^{-i\theta}) )$$

Comment: Thanks, but I have already seen this form. My objective here is to make it more explicit with the "multiple integrals" idea.

Comment: @IanMateus: You said if there was another approach and this is one. You are welcome.

Comment: @Argon: Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{k\theta} \over k^{2u+1}}:\ {\large ?}\,,
     \qquad u\in\mathbb{N}}$

> $$
> \mbox{Lets}\quad{\cal J}_{u}\pars{\theta}
> \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{k\theta} \over k^{2u + 1}}
> $$

\begin{align}
{\cal J}_{u}\pars{\theta}&={\cal J}_{u}\pars{\theta} - {\cal J}_{u}\pars{0}=
\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u}'\pars{\theta - t}\,\dd t
=
{\cal J}'_{u}\pars{0}\theta + \int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u}''\pars{\theta - t}t
\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
{\cal J}'_{u}\pars{0}\theta + \half\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u}'''\pars{\theta - t}
t^{2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
{\cal J}'_{u}\pars{0}\theta
+ {1 \over 2.3}\,{\cal J}'''_{u}\pars{0}\theta^{3}
+{1 \over 2.3}\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u}^{\tt\pars{IV}}\pars{\theta - t}t^{3}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{N}
{{\cal J}_{u}^{\tt\pars{2n + 1}}\pars{0} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,\theta^{2n + 1}
+ {1 \over \pars{2N + 1}!}
\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u}^{\tt\pars{2N + 2}}\pars{\theta - t}t^{2N + 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> Also,
>   \begin{align}
> {\cal J}_{u}^{\tt\pars{2n + 1}}\pars{0} &= \pars{-1}^{n + 1}
> \zeta\pars{2u - 2n}\quad\mbox{with}\quad
> \pars{~2u - 2n \geq 2\quad\imp\quad n \leq u + 1~}
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{and}\quad
> {\cal J}_{u}^{\tt\pars{2n}}\pars{\theta}
> =\pars{-1}^{n}{\cal J}_{u - n}\pars{\theta}
> \end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
{\cal J}_{u}\pars{\theta}&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{N}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,
{\zeta\pars{2u - 2n} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,\theta^{2n + 1}
+ {\pars{-1}^{N + 1} \over \pars{2N + 1}!}
\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{u - N - 1}\pars{\theta - t}t^{2N + 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}
With $\ds{N = u - 1}$:
\begin{align}
{\cal J}_{u}\pars{\theta}&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{u - 1}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{\zeta\pars{2u - 2n} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,\theta^{2n + 1}
+ {\pars{-1}^{u} \over \pars{2u - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{\theta}{\cal J}_{0}\pars{\theta - t}t^{2u - 1}\,\dd t
\end{align}
Since the OP reports that
$\ds{{\cal J}_{0}\pars{\theta} = \half\pars{\pi - \theta}}$:
\begin{align}\!\!\!
\color{#00f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{k\theta} \over k^{2u + 1}}}&=
\color{#00f}{\sum_{n = 0}^{u - 1}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{\zeta\pars{2u - 2n} \over \pars{2n + 1}!}\,\theta^{2n + 1}}
+
\color{#00f}{{\pars{-1}^{u}\pi \over 4u\pars{2u - 1}!}\,\theta^{2u}
+ {\pars{-1}^{u + 1} \over 4u\pars{2u + 1}\pars{2u - 1}!}\,\theta^{2u + 1}}
\\[3mm]&\mbox{with}\quad u \geq 1
\end{align}