# Evaluate the integral of a function defined by an infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to evaluate 
 $\,\,\,\displaystyle \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \! \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin nx}{n^3} \, \mathrm{d}x$ and  $\displaystyle\int \limits_0^{\pi} \! \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos nx}{n^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$

I have already proved that the infinite series' are continuous and that the derivative of the first is equal to the second. I'm not sure how to use that information to evaluate the integrals however.

Comment: Do the series converge uniformly?

Comment: If it converges uniformly do you see further procedure...

Comment: The series do converge uniformly do I need to think about Riemann integrability?

Comment: It is not necessary to check for riemann integrability and all... please convince yourself that you can change integral and sum if it is uniformly convergent and then it would be easy to see the result

Comment: I'm getting a little confused as to how I would go on from there?

Comment: I said you can surely interchange integral and sum.. Is that a bit clear now?

Comment: I understood that part, I just meant the steps after that. Would you then take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The series converges uniformly. Then $\int_0^{2\pi} \sum\frac{\sin nx}{n^3}=\sum \int\frac{\sin nx}{n^3}$.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I just don't know how you'd go on after that

Comment: since every $\int\frac{\sin nx}{n^3}=0$, then the sum is also zero. Therefore, the sum of the series in the question is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{n^3}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sin nx\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\left(\left.-\frac1n\cos nx\right|_0^{2\pi}\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\cdot 0=0$$

Can you explain the above?

Comment: The first equality is because the series' converge uniformly so you can interchange the integral and summation and then the rest follows. Is that right? Is there anything more I should think about?

Comment: Well, I meant why the result is ""logically"" zero ?

Comment: Because that is the pointwise limit of the series?

Comment: Nop. Look at $\;\sin nx\;$ in the interval $\;[0,2\pi]\;$ ...

Comment: So it's because the area of the graph above x=0 is the same as the area below?

Comment: Well, that's one one to put it...yes.

Comment: As in, it's symmetrical about x=0

Comment: Well, it's anti-symmetric wrt the line $\;x=\frac\pi2\;$ , which is what matters to us.

Answer (score 0):

Well, something to be said for evaluating one of the sums.  I do it here for the cosine:  [Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552640/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2/552649#552649). The result for this series is $x^2/4-\pi x/2+\pi^2/6$ for $x \in [0,2\pi)$.  The integral of this series over $[0,\pi]$ is $\pi^3/12 -\pi^3/4 +\pi^3/6 =0$.

For the sine series, integrate the previous sum with respect to $x$, such that the result at $x=0$ is zero; the sum is $x^3/12-\pi x^2/4 +\pi^2 x/6$.  You can show that the integral over $[0,2 \pi)$ is zero.