# Differentiability of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$, is it not differentiable at $0$ and $2\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

Let $f : [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$. I already know that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, 2\pi)$ and that $f^{\prime}(x) = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ there.

What about $0$ and $2\pi$? Is it differentiable at those points?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2925275/42969

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate of  [Differentiabliliy of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925275/differentiabliliy-of-fx-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2)