# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^4} = \tfrac{1}{12}x^2 (\pi - \tfrac{1}{2}x)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is given:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^4} = \tfrac{1}{12}x^2 (\pi - \tfrac{1}{2}x)^2
\end{equation}
My first attempt to prove this equality was to use Mellin transform, but I fail to show the result.

Comment: Why don't you simply compute the Fourier series of the right hand side (when considered as periodic function which is what the equality is meant to be)

Comment: The formula holds for $x\in [0, 2\pi]$, e.g., $\mathrm{LHS} \ne \mathrm{RHS}$ for $x = -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos(nx) }{ n^{2} } = \zeta(2) - \frac{ \pi \, x}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{4}\tag 1
\end{align}
integrate to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n x)}{n^{3}} = \zeta(2) \, x - \frac{\pi \, x^{2}}{4} + \frac{x^{3}}{12}.
\end{align}
Integrate once again so we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{4}} = \zeta(4) - \frac{\zeta(2) \, x^{2}}{2} + \frac{\pi \, x^{3}}{12} - \frac{x^{4}}{48}.
\end{align}
So:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n^4} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^4}=\\\zeta(4)-\zeta(4)+\frac{\zeta(2)x^2}{2}-\frac{\pi x^3}{12}+\frac{x^4}{48}=\frac{\pi^2 x^2}{12}-\frac{\pi x^3}{12}+\frac{x^4}{48}=\frac{x^2}{12}(\pi-\frac{x}{2})^2$$

To prove the equality $(1)$ you can check here [Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552640/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Where did $\zeta(4)$ come from?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}=\zeta(4)$

Comment: No, upon your second integration

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x}\sum\frac{\sin (nt)}{n^3}\;dt=\sum\frac{\cos (nx)}{n^4}-\sum\frac{\cos (0)}{n^4}$, and $\sum\frac{\cos (0)}{n^4}=\sum\frac{1}{n^4}=\zeta(4)$

Comment: I see, thanks!!

Comment: Why not mention for which $x$ this is true?

Comment: As River Li mentions in the comments, the formula holds for $x\in [0,2π]$.