# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1} \cos(x) \ \mathrm dx = \Gamma(a) \cos (\pi a/2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

My goal is to calculate the integral

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1} \cos(x) dx = \Gamma(a) \cos (\pi a/2)$,

where $0<a<1$,
and my textbook provides the hint: integrate $z^{a-1} e^{iz}$ around the boundary of a quarter disk.

However, I couldn't figure out how to control the integral over the quarter arc. Any hints?

Comment: This question was studied in detail here at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479586/evaluate-int-0-infty-cost-tz-1dt-gammaz-cos-frac-pi-z2) by some of the very same people who participated in this (the current) thread but this being a duplicate was apparently overlooked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \, z^{a-1} \, e^{i z}$$

where $C$ is a quarter circle of radius $R$ in the 1st quadrant (real and imaginary $> 0$), with a small quarter circle of radius $\epsilon$ about the origin cut out (to avoid the branch point at the origin).

This integral is equal to

$$\int_{\epsilon}^R dx \, x^{a-1} \, e^{i x} + i R^a \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i a \theta} e^{i R \cos{\theta}} \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}}\\+ i \int_R^{\epsilon} dy \, e^{i \pi (a-1)/2} y^{a-1} e^{-y} + i \epsilon^a \int_{\pi/2}^0 d\phi \, e^{i a \phi} \, e^{i \epsilon e^{i \phi}}$$

We note that the second integral vanishes as $R\to\infty$ because $\sin{\theta} \gt 2 \theta/\pi$, so that the magnitude of that integral is bounded by

$$R^a \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le R^a \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{2}{\pi R^{1-a}}$$

We also note that the fourth integral vanishes as $\epsilon^a$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.  In the third integral, we write $i=e^{i \pi/2}$ to make a simplification.

The contour integral is zero by Cauchy's Theorem (no poles in the interior of $C$).  Ths we have (+)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \, x^{a-1} \, e^{i x} - e^{i \pi a/2} \int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^{a-1} \, e^{-y}=0$$

We use the definition of the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(a) = \int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^{a-1} \, e^{-y}$$

and take real parts of (+) to obtain the sought-after result.

Comment: Was waiting for you to show up :p

Comment: This is crystal clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Ron Gordon, I was wondering about one thing. What if we take instead of a quarter circle a random arc. Wouldn't the integral involving $R\to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ still be $0$ and that makes gamma integrand something like symmetric from all rays emanating from origin?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{a - 1}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\Gamma\pars{a}\cos\pars{\pi a \over 2}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

*Note that* $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}
\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x}$.

---

With the change of variable
$x \equiv \expo{\ic\pi/2}\,t$, we'll have:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
\Re\int_{0}^{-\ic\infty}\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/2}t}^{a - 1}
\expo{-t}\,\ic\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
\Re\bracks{\expo{\ic\pi a/2}
\int_{0}^{-\ic\infty}t^{a - 1}
\expo{-t}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Re\braces{\expo{\ic\pi a/2}\bracks{-\int_{\infty}^{0}t^{a - 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd x}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Re\bracks{\expo{\ic\pi a/2}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a - 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd x\ }^{\ds{=\ \Gamma\pars{a}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\ \Re\bracks{\expo{\ic\pi a/2}}\ }
_{\ds{=\ \cos\pars{\pi a/2}}}
\Gamma\pars{a}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mbox{}
\\
&\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a - 1}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x
=
\Gamma\pars{a}\cos\pars{\pi a \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @a12345 You're welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently read a short, yet interesting, article by Boas and Friedman where the authors calculated this same integral by using a different kind of contour:

a triangle with vertices $-p_{1}, \;\ p_{2}, \;\ (p_{1}+p_{2})i$.

Consider $R(z)e^{iz}$, where R(z) is a rational function that vanishes at $\infty$

Then, $p_{1}, \;\ p_{2}$ are taken to be sufficiently large as to enclose the poles in the UHP.

Instead of using the arc of a circle in the first quadrant, they use a straight line segment.

By letting $p_{1}, \;\ p_{2} \to \infty$ the integral over the real axis is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues in the UHP.

This computation is claimed to be simpler because the slope of the triangular contour is bounded away from 0 in the UHP.

Connect the points $z=p, \;\ z=pi$ with a line rather than the arc of a circle.

On this line, $|dz|=\sqrt{2}dy$ and $\frac{1}{|z|}\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{p}$.

It follows immediately that the integral over the line is bounded by a constant times

$p^{s-1}\int_{0}^{p}e^{-y}dy\leq p^{s-1}$ which tends to 0 as $p\to \infty$ since $s<1$.

I have not included all of the intricacies, so if any one is interested in looking over this article it is in JSTOR.  Look for "a simplification in certain contour integrals".