# Gamma Function Contour Integration

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration, gamma-function

So, I've been trying to prove the following integral related to the gamma function, and I'm really banging my head against the wall over this:

$$\int_0^\infty{\cos{t^p}}dt=\frac{1}{p}\cos({\frac{\pi}{2p}})\Gamma({\frac{1}{p}})$$
Note: $p>1$

Does anyone have any ideas or resources which could point me in the right direction for proving this?  I have tried complex contour integration using a semi-circle, messing around with Hankel's representation, and a few other things.  However, I can't come up with anything that looks remotely similar to this.  Any insight would be GREATLY appreciated!

Edit: I have also tried ideas in this post: [Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1} \cos(x) \ \mathrm dx = \Gamma(a) \cos (\pi a/2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582787/calculating-int-0-infty-xa-1-cosx-mathrm-dx-gammaa-cos-p/582817#582817) . For some reason, I am still not ending up with the desired expression.

Comment: Since $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx=\Gamma\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)=\tfrac1n\cdot\Gamma\Big(\tfrac1n\Big)$, it should come as no surprise that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cos(x^n)dx = \cos\frac\pi{2n}\cdot\Gamma\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)dx = \sin\frac\pi{2n}\cdot\Gamma\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)$. Also, a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739954/how-to-solve-int-0-infty-sinx2-rm-dx#comment1543105_739954) has been asked just recently.

Comment: @Lucian I don't know; that is definitely not obvious to me.  Could you please flesh out the details a bit?

Comment: Let $t^n=ix^n$. What are the real and imaginary parts of $\sqrt[n]i$ ?

Comment: @Lucian Well, yeah; that would give us the $\cos({\frac{pi}{2n}})$ term, but that substitution messes up the bounds, right? We'd have to integrate from 0 to $i\infty$, correct?

Comment: [Not necessarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Complex_analysis). See [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). Besides: a little bit of handwaving never hurt anyone. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to derive the result from scratch using contour integration (and justify the substitution that Lucian made), consider $f(z) = e^{iz^{p}}$ and integrate around a sector/wedge of radius $R$ that makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2p}$ with the positive real axis.

I'm just going to consider the case where $p$ is an integer greater than $1$.

Then

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx + \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/(2p)} f(Re^{it}) iRe^{it}\ dt  + \int^{\infty}_{0} f(te^{i \pi / (2p)}) e^{i \pi/(2p)} \ dt =0 $$

But

$$\Big| \int_{0}^{\pi/(2p)} f(Re^{it}) iRe^{it}\ dt \Big| =\int_{0}^{\pi/(2p)} |e^{iR^{p}e^{ipt}} | R \ dt = \int_{0}^{\pi/(2p)} e^{-R^{p} \sin pt} R \ dt$$

$$ \le \int_{0}^{\pi /(2p)} e^{-R^{p} \frac{2}{\pi} pt} R \ dt \  \ (\text{Jordan's inequality})$$

$$ = R \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{pR^{p}} \Big(1-e^{-R^{p}} \Big) \to 0 \ \text{as} \ R \to \infty  \ \text{since p >1}$$

And

$$\int_{\infty}^{0} f(te^{i \pi / (2p)}) e^{i \pi/(2p)} \ dt = - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{it^{p}e^{i \pi/2}}e^{i \pi/(2p)} \ dt = -e^{i \pi/(2p)}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{p}}  \ dt  $$

So we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{ix^{p}} \ dx = e^{i \pi /(2p)} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{p}} \ dt$$

Or

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \Big( \cos(x^{p}) + i \sin(x^{p}) \Big) \ dx =  \left[ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2p} \right) + i\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2p} \right) \right]\frac{1}{p}\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{p} \right)$$

If you want to extend the result to all real values of $p$ greater than $1$, indent the contour around the origin and show that it's contribution is vanishing small as the radius of the indentation goes to $0$. The computation is very similar to the one showing that the integral around the big wedge vanishes.

Comment: Very good response; thank you!  Do we not need a branch cut for p>1 though?  What if p = 3/2 for example?

Comment: Yes. If p is not an integer, there is a branch point at the origin.  So we need a branch cut somewhere.  Have it running down the negative imaginary axis (or along the negative real axis) and then indent the contour around the origin.  Then what is left, as I mentioned above, is to show that the contribution from the indentation goes to $0$ as the radius of the indentation goes to $0$. Basically just replace $R$ with $r$ in the estimation I did above, and then let $r$ go to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, sir!