# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n)}{n^4}=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\frac{\pi }{12}-\frac{1}{48}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Proving $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n)}{n^4}=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\frac{\pi }{12}-\frac{1}{48}$$

I tried with Wolfram but it couldn't give me any clear value as shown below
[image]

The numerical value of Wolfram not different of my closed-form.
Can anyone explain how the $.5(Li_4(e^{-i}+Li_4(e^{i}))$ equal the above closed-form

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's answer is essentially trivial. $$\mathrm{Li}_4(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^4}$$ by definition. And WA is saying that your sum is the real part of $\mathrm{Li}_4(e^i)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,  your explaination is ok , now, how can I prove the closed form depending on what you posted?

Comment: I don't know, otherwise, I would have posted an answer. The question is not trivial, but Wolfram's answer is. :)

Comment: This is essentially the same (quite a bit simpler in fact) as the computation at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153068/). I can present the Mellin transform method but as there are other more basic approaches, I will wait for a while and watch the thread and decide later.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. I found an answer among my posts at this [MSE link II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985778/weighted-sum-of-cosines/).

Comment: @Marko Riedel Interesting. I myself was hoping for a more elegant (and less dependent on advanced, non-trivial theorems) solution, which might still exist for this particular case. Therefore I don't feel like we should close the question just yet.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, thanks.

Comment: @Ehegh Which above value? As I said, the fact that $\sum \frac{\cos n}{n^4} = \frac{1}{2}\left(Li_4(e^{-i})+Li_4(e^{i})\right)$ is trivial, so proving the sum formula is equal to your closed for is all you need.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks

Comment: @Uncountable I wasn't suggesting to close. In fact I am usually in favor of variety on this site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start with :
$$\tag{1}f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n^4}$$
and observe that (from the ["Sawtooth Wave" Fourier series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html) with $L=2\pi$ and $x=2X$) :
$$\tag{2}f^{(3)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n\,x)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}2,\quad \text{for}\;x\in(0,2\pi)$$

At this point it remains only to integrate $(2)$ three times with the appropriate constant of integration :

$$\tag{3}f^{(2)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{-\cos(n\,x)}{n^2}=C+\frac{\pi}2x-\frac 14x^2$$
with $\;\displaystyle C=f^{(2)}(0)=-\zeta(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}6$.
$$\tag{4}f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{-\sin(n\,x)}{n^3}=-\frac{\pi^2}6x+\frac{\pi}4x^2-\frac 1{12}x^3$$
(since $f'(0)=0$)
and the final solution :
$$\tag{5}f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n^4}=\zeta(4)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}x^2+\frac{\pi}{12}x^3-\frac 1{48}x^4,\quad \text{for}\;x\in(0,2\pi)$$
Of course $x=1$ and $\zeta(4)=\dfrac{\pi^4}{90}$ will return the wished conclusion.

### Generalization

It is clear that $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n^{2m}}\;$ and $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n\,x)}{n^{2m-1}}\;$ may be evaluated by this method for $x\in(0;2\pi)$ and $m$ any positive integer. The polynomials obtained are well known since they correspond to the Bernoulli polynomials as given in [Abramowitz and Stegun $(23.1.18)$ and $(23.1.17)$](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_805.htm).

The remaining cases $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n^{2m-1}}\;$ and $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n\,x)}{n^{2m}}\;$ are not so easy to evaluate and got the name of [Clausen functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html) $\;\operatorname{Cl}_{2m-1}(x)\;$ and $\;\operatorname{Cl}_{2m}(x)$.

The origin of the difficulty is that $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Cl}_1(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\cos(n\,x)}{n}=-\ln(2\,\sin(x/2))\;$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321736/the-fourier-series-sum-n-1-infty-1-n-cos-nx)) implying that the integrals will be harder to evaluate (except for specific fractions of $\pi$).

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{n} \over n^{4}}} =
\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{\expo{\ic}}^{n} \over n^{4}} = \Re\on{Li}_{4}\pars{\expo{\ic}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\left[%
\on{Li}_{4}\pars{\exp\pars{2\pi\ic{1 \over 2\pi}}}\right.
\\[2mm] & \left. \phantom{AA}+
\pars{-1}^{4}\,
\on{Li}_{4}\pars{%
\exp\pars{-2\pi\ic{1 \over 2\pi}}}
\right]
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\bracks{-\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{4} \over 4!}\on{B}_{4}\pars{1 \over 2\pi}}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{Li}_{s}\ \mbox{and}\ \on{B}_{n}}$ are the *Polylogarithm Function* and a *Bernoulli Polynomial*, respectively.

The bracket enclosed identity in
(\ref{1}) is the [$\ds{Jonqui\grave{e}re\ Inversion\ Formula}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions).
$$
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\on{B}_{4}\pars{x} = x^{4} - 2x^{3} + x^{2} - {1 \over 30}
$$

Therefore, with (\ref{1}),
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{n} \over n^{4}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\braces{-\,{16\pi^{4} \over 24}
\bracks{\pars{1 \over 2\pi}^{4} - 2\pars{1 \over 2\pi}^{3} + \pars{1 \over 2\pi}^{2} - {1 \over 30}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\pi^{4} \over 90}- {\pi^{2} \over 12} + {\pi \over 12} - {1 \over 48}}} \approx 0.5008
\\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

By using the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos(nx) }{ n^{2} } = \zeta(2) - \frac{ \pi \, x}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{4}
\end{align}
integrate with respect to $x$ from zero to $t$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n t)}{n^{3}} = \zeta(2) \, t - \frac{\pi \, t^{2}}{4} + \frac{t^{3}}{12}.
\end{align}
Integrate once again in a similar manor to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{4}} = \zeta(4) - \frac{\zeta(2) \, x^{2}}{2} + \frac{\pi \, t^{3}}{12} - \frac{x^{4}}{48}.
\end{align}
Upon letting $x=1$ the above results yield
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^{2}} &= \zeta(2) + \frac{1 - 2 \pi}{4} \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n^{3}} &= \zeta(2) + \frac{1 - 3 \pi}{12} \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^{4}} &= \zeta(4) - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} + \frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{48}.
\end{align}

Comment: I think there is a problem with the signs of terms

Comment: @Ehegh  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Let $k$ be a nonnegative integer.

Contour integration shows that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n^{2k-1}} = - \frac{1}{2} \, \Im\, \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{\pi \left(\cot (\pi z)-\color{red}{i} \right)e^{iz}}{z^{2k-1}},0 \right]$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n)}{n^{2k}} =  - \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \,  \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{\pi \left(\cot (\pi z)-\color{red}{i} \right)e^{iz}}{z^{2k}},0 \right].$$

See my previous answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829774/16033) for an explanation of why we use $\cot(\pi z)-i$ and not just $\cot(\pi z)$.

Basically it has to do with the fact that the magnitude of $e^{iz}$ is unbounded in the lower half-plane.

At the origin, we have the Laurent series expansion $$ \begin{align}  \pi \left(\cot(\pi z)-i  \right)e^{iz} &=\small \left(\frac{1}{z}- i \pi - 2\zeta(2)z -2 \zeta(4) x^{3} + O(z^{5}) \right) \left( 1+iz- \frac{z^{2}}{2!}-  \frac{iz^{3}}{3!} + \frac{z^{4}}{4!} + O(z^{5}) \right) \\ & = \small \frac{1}{z} + i \left(1-\pi \right) + \left(- \frac{1}{2!} +\pi  - 2\zeta(2) \right)z + i \left(- \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{\pi}{2!}  -2 \zeta(2) \right)z^{2} \\ &+ \small  \left(\frac{1}{4!} -\frac{\pi}{3!} + \frac{2 \zeta(2)}{2!} - 2 \zeta(4) \right)z^{3} + O(z^{4}) . \end{align}$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n)}{n} = \frac{\pi -1}{2}, $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n)}{n^{2}} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2} + \zeta(2),  $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n)}{n^{3}} = \frac{1}{12} - \frac{\pi}{4} + \zeta(2), $$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n)}{n^{4}} = -\frac{1}{48} + \frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} + \zeta(4), $$ and so on.