# Any possible suspects for $\zeta(3)$?

Tags: zeta-functions

I'm young, and have been studying this number for quite some time. Possible suspects for a closed form i have personally encountered through **ghetto makeshift** studyies are:

- **Euler-Mascheroni** Constant
- **Glaisher** Constant
- Cube root of two, i.e $\sqrt[3]2$
- $\displaystyle\frac{\pi\tanh[\pi\sqrt{3}]}{\sqrt{3}}$
- Random values of Inverse Tangent, Inverse Hyperbolic tangent.

The **cube root of two** and Euler's Constant are especially likely suspects, but I'm confident that the cube root of two is a coefficient for the true closed form. They appear frequently when I'm trying different methods to evaluate $\zeta(3)$.

I would like to hear your opinions, if you have any, about the relationship between known constants and $\zeta(3)$. I know many people believe that odd values of/for $\zeta(3)$ are unique in a sense where they are unrelated to other known constants, but I am hoping this is not true.

Also, I was wondering if someone could help me find the closed form for the real part of a complex valued **Digamma function**, or if this [series](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum_n%3D0%5EInfinity+%28-1%29%5En*Zeta%284n%2B2%29%2F%282n%2B1%29) is related to $\zeta(3)$ at all.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What is your question exactly?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The series you mention can be expressed in terms of $~\dfrac{\sinh\big(\pi\sqrt i~\big)}{\sin\big(\pi\sqrt i~\big)}$

Comment: A lot of work has been done, trying to relate $\zeta(3)$ to other constants. Type "integer relations" into the internet,  and see what comes back at you.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you share your work on Apery's Constant with me?

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

If you look at sequence $\rm A002117$ at $\rm OEIS$, you will find a very nice approximation of Apéry's constant . It is given by $$\zeta(3) \approx\frac{236 }{197}\log ^3(2)-\frac{283\pi}{394}   \log ^2(2)+\frac{11\pi ^2}{394}  \log (2)+\frac{209}{394} \log ^3\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{93 \pi  C}{197}-\frac{5}{197}$$ and the first $22$ digits are correct.

Comment: Seemingly remarkable mathematical coincidences are easy to generate... For all those constants sitting within that expression, 22 significant digits are a meager prize...

Answer (score 1):

No closed-form expression is known for $\zeta(3)$. The closest you can get to an expresison involing known constants are due to Plouffe and Borwein & Bradley:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\zeta(3)&=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)},\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\,\binom {2n}n} &= -\frac{4}{3}\,\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 3^2}\,\left(\zeta(2, \tfrac{1}{3})-\zeta(2,\tfrac{2}{3}) \right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Moreover, in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/a-new-formula-for-aperys-constant-and-other-zetas) we have:

$$
\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(3) = \frac{\pi^3}{24}\sqrt{2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3(e^{\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3(e^{2\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}.
$$

You can also check out [this paper by Vepstas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775v4.pdf), which provides a nice generalization to some of these identities.