# Calculating in closed form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^4(m^2+n^2)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How would you tackle this series by real analysis?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^4(m^2+n^2)}$$

Comment: Assuming that you want to compute the sum (the convergence is rather obvious), what makes you think that the sum can be expressed in a simpler way?

Comment: @ajotatxe a long time ago I saw it in a paper I don't recollect now in which one, and as far as I can remember it had a closed form.

Comment: Value 1.1260088410668 is not found by ISC http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: @r9m I'd like too. Actually, I'd like to see any solution by means of real analysis. :-)

Comment: @GEdgar as regards my series and integrals, for major part of them ISC is not helpful unfortunately, that is for more than 99% of them. I stopped using it a long time ago.

Comment: The Plouffe's article linked in my answer shows that there are nice closed forms if we replace $m^4$ by $m^2$ or $m^6$. The case $m^4$ is not so easy to deal with.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I know, that's why I was particularly interested in it. Thanks for the job (+1).

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist: ok, I think I managed to prove that no "nice" closed form exists, unless we find one for $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n^5},$$ highly unlikely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=\frac{-1+m\pi\coth(m\pi)}{2m^2}\tag{1}$$
our sum equals:
$$ -\frac{\zeta(6)}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\coth(m\pi)}{m^5}=-\frac{\pi\zeta(5)-\zeta(6)}{2}+\pi\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^5(e^{2m\pi}-1)}\tag{2}$$
and maybe the last series has a nice closed form. [Here](http://www.linas.org/math/plouffe-ram.pdf) there is a related paper.

Following Simon Plouffe,
$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^5(e^{2m\pi}-1)}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\text{Li}_5(e^{-2\pi m})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z)}{(2\pi)^z}\zeta(z+5)\zeta(z)\,dz.\tag{3}$$
If now we set $f(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{(2\pi)^z}\zeta(z+5)\zeta(z)$, we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right)&=&-\frac{\zeta(5)}{2},\\\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=-1\right)&=&\frac{\pi^5}{540}\\\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=-3\right)&=&-\frac{\pi^5}{540}\\\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=-4\right)&=&\frac{2\pi^4}{3}\zeta'(-4)\\\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=-5\right)&=&-\frac{\pi^5}{1890}\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence a closed form for $(2)$ just depends on a closed form for $\zeta'(-4)$, or, by the reflection formula, on a closed form for:
$$\zeta'(5)=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log n}{n^5}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: (+1). The following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/) showns how to do the Plouffe computations.

Comment: Very nice reference +1