# A Ramanujan sum involving $\sinh$

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, residue-calculus, poisson-summation-formula

Today, in a personal communication, I was asked to prove the classical result
$$\boxed{ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\sinh(\pi n)} = \frac{\pi^3}{360}}\tag{CR} $$
which I believe is due to Ramanujan. My proof can be found [here](http://mathb.in/21605) and it is based on the closed form for $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^2+n^2}$ and double counting. **I would use this question for collecting alternative proofs**. I am already aware that standard techniques for tackling series with a similar structure are

1. The [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula);
2. The residue theorem coupled with the Laplace transform of $\text{Li}_k$ (I used this approach due to Simon Plouffe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330213/calculating-in-closed-form-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty-frac1m4/1330250#1330250), for instance);
3. [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) related to Gaussian integers;
4. Identities involving Dirichlet's series, since $$r_2(N)=\left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:a^2+b^2=N\}\right|=4 \sum_{d\mid N}\chi_4(d)$$
   (this can be regarded as an analytic-combinatorial equivalent of the statement "*$\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD*").

I also know that a cornerstone is given by Zucker's *The Summation of Series of Hyperbolic Functions*, 1979. Let us see if we can devise a *very* short proof of $(\text{CR})$ through these ingredients or other ones.

Comment: A *folklore* note: a straightforward consequence of $(\text{CR})$ is $\pi^3\approx 31$.

Comment: Thanks for that website MathB for sharing math content (like pastebin) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3} \frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)}
= \frac{\pi^3}{360}.$$

Using $$\frac{1}{\sinh(x)} = \frac{2}{e^x-e^{-x}}
= 2\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}$$
this is the same as

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3}
\frac{e^{-n\pi}}{1-e^{-2n\pi}}
= \frac{\pi^3}{720}.$$

The sum  term may  be evaluated  using harmonic  summation techniques.
Since  this  method  has  not   been  presented  I  will  detail  this
calculation here.

Let $p$ be a positive integer and introduce

$$S(x;p) =
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2p+1}}
\frac{e^{-nx}}{1-e^{-2nx}}.$$

We will evaluate  $S(\pi;p)$ using a functional  equation for $S(x;p)$
that is obtained by inverting its Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{2p+1}}, \quad
\mu_k = k
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-2x}} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty 
\sum_{q\ge 0} e^{- (2 q+1) x} x^{s-1} dx
=  \sum_{q\ge 0}  \int_0^\infty e^{-(2q+1)x} x^{s-1} dx 
\\= \Gamma(s) \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{(2q+1)^s}
= \left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
with fundamental strip $\langle 1, \infty\rangle.$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x;p)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+2p}}\right)
\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \zeta(s+2p+1)
\\ \text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{2p+1}} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \left(1-\frac{2}{2^{s+2p+1}}\right) \zeta(s+2p+1)$$
for $\Re(s+2p+1) > 1$ or $\Re(s) \gt -2p.$

The Mellin inversion integral here is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate  by shifting it to the left  for an expansion about
zero.

Fortunately the  trivial zeros of  the two zeta function  terms cancel
the poles of the gamma function  term. The first term cancels those at
$-2m$ where $m\ge 1$ and the second  one the odd ones from $-2p-3$ on,
which leaves  the poles at $s=1$,  and $-2q-1$ with $0\le  q\le p.$ It
would appear there is a pole at $s=-2p$ but this is not the case since
we  have two  simple poles  among  the five  terms but  also two  zero
values,  making for  cancelation. The  pole  at $s=0$  is canceled  as
well.

For the residue at $s=1$ we find

$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{2^{2p+1}-1}{2^{2p+1}} 
\times 1 \times \zeta(2p+2) \frac{1}{x}
= \frac{2^{2p+1}-1}{2^{2p+2}} 
\frac{(-1)^{p} B_{2p+2}  (2\pi)^{2p+2}}{2 (2p+2)!} \frac{1}{x}
\\ = (2^{2p+1}-1) 
\frac{(-1)^{p} B_{2p+2} \pi^{2p+2}}{2 (2p+2)!} \frac{1}{x}.$$

The negative odd values at $s=-2q-1$ yield

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{-2q-1}}\right) 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2p-2q-1}}\right)
\frac{(-1)^{2q+1}}{(2q+1)!} \zeta(-2q-1) \zeta(2p-2q) x^{2q+1}
\\ = (1-2^{2q+1}) 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2p-2q-1}}\right)
\frac{1}{(2q+1)!} \frac{B_{2q+2}}{2q+2}
\frac{(-1)^{p-q+1} B_{2p-2q} (2\pi)^{2p-2q}}{2(2p-2q)!}
x^{2q+1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (1-2^{2q+1}) 
(2^{2p-2q-1}-1)
\frac{(-1)^{p-q+1}}{(2q+1)!}
\frac{B_{2q+2} B_{2p-2q} \pi^{2p-2q}}{(2p-2q)! (q+1)}
x^{2q+1}.$$

Shifting to  $\Re(s) = -2p -3/2$ we get

$$S(x;p) =
(2^{2p+1}-1) 
\frac{(-1)^{p} B_{2p+2} \pi^{2p+2}}{2 (2p+2)!} \frac{1}{x}
\\ +
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^p
(1-2^{2q+1}) 
(2^{2p-2q-1}-1)
\frac{(-1)^{p-q+1}}{(2q+1)!}
\frac{B_{2q+2} B_{2p-2q} \pi^{2p-2q}}{(2p-2q)! (q+1)}
x^{2q+1}
\\ + \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{-2p-3/2-i\infty}^{-2p-3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

We will turn this into the promised functional equation.

Substitute $s = -2p - t$ in the remainder integral to get

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2+i\infty}^{3/2-i\infty}
\left(1-2^{2p+t}\right) 
\left(1-2^t\right)
\Gamma(-2p-t) \zeta(-2p-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^{t+2p} dt$$
which is

$$\frac{x^{2p}}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
\left(1-2^{2p+t}\right) 
\left(1-2^t\right)
\Gamma(-2p-t) \zeta(-2p-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^{t} dt.$$

In view of  the desired functional equation we  now use the functional
equation  of the Riemann  zeta function  on $Q(s)$  to prove  that the
integrand of the last integral is in fact $(-1)^p Q(t)/\pi^{2p+2t}.$

Start with the functional equation
$$\zeta(1-s) = \frac{2}{2^s\pi^s} 
\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
and substitute this into $Q(s)$ to obtain

$$Q(s) = 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+2p}}\right)
\frac{\zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^s}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(s+2p+1)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} 
(2^s-1) \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+2p}}\right)
\pi^s \frac{\zeta(s+2p+1)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(1-s).$$

Apply the functional equation again  (this time to $\zeta(s+2p+1)$) to
get

$$Q(s) =  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi^s}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
(2^s-1) \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+2p}}\right)
\frac{2}{2^{-2p-s} \pi^{-2p-s}}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi (-2p-s)}{2}\right)
\\ \times \Gamma(-2p-s) \zeta(-2p-s) \zeta(1-s)
\\ = \frac{\pi^s}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
(2^s-1) (2^{2p+s}-1)
\pi^{2p+s}
(-1)^p \cos\left(\frac{-\pi s}{2}\right)
\\ \times \Gamma(-2p-s) \zeta(-2p-s) \zeta(1-s)$$

and  we finally get
$$Q(s) =  (-1)^p \pi^{2p+2s} (1-2^s) (1-2^{2p+s})
\Gamma(-2p-s) \zeta(-2p-s) \zeta(1-s)$$

thus proving the claim.

Return to the remainder integral and re-write it as follows:

$$(-1)^p \frac{(x/\pi)^{2p}}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
(-1)^p \pi^{2p+2t}
\left(1-2^{2p+t}\right) 
\left(1-2^t\right)
\\ \times \Gamma(-2p-t) \zeta(-2p-t) \zeta(1-t)
(x/\pi^2)^{t} dt.$$

so that  the fact of it being  a multiple of the  defining integral of
$S(\pi^2/x; p)$ becomes readily apparent.

We have established the functional equation

$$\color{green}
{S(x;p) =
(2^{2p+1}-1) 
\frac{(-1)^{p} B_{2p+2} \pi^{2p+2}}{2 (2p+2)!} \frac{1}{x}
\\ +
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^p
(1-2^{2q+1}) 
(2^{2p-2q-1}-1)
\frac{(-1)^{p-q+1}}{(2q+1)!}
\frac{B_{2q+2} B_{2p-2q} \pi^{2p-2q}}{(2p-2q)! (q+1)}
x^{2q+1}
\\ + (-1)^p \left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^{2p} S(\pi^2/x;p).}$$

Now the value  $x=\pi$ is obviously special here (fixed  point) and we
get for  $p=2r+1$ with $r\ge  0$ ($p$  even yields a  Bernoulli number
identity)

$$S(\pi; 2r+1) = 
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{4r+3}}
\frac{e^{-n\pi}}{1-e^{-2n\pi}}
= - \frac{\pi^{4r+3}}{4} 
(2^{4r+3}-1) 
\frac{B_{4r+4}}{(4r+4)!}
\\ + \frac{\pi^{4r+3}}{4} \sum_{q=0}^{2r+1}
(1-2^{2q+1}) 
(2^{4r+1-2q}-1)
\frac{(-1)^{q}}{(2q+1)!}
\frac{B_{2q+2} B_{4r+2-2q}}{(4r+2-2q)! (q+1)}.$$

We obtain a rational multiple of $\pi^{4r+3}.$ Scale by two to get
for

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3} \frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)}, 
\quad \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^7} \frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)},
\\ \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{11}} \frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)}, 
\quad \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{15}} \frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)},
\quad \ldots$$

the values

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{\frac {{\pi }^{3}}{360}},\quad
{\frac {13\,{\pi }^{7}}{453600}},\quad
{\frac {4009\,{\pi }^{11}}{13621608000}},\quad
{\frac {13739\,{\pi }^{15}}{4547140416000}},\quad \ldots}$$

These are dominated by the first term

$$\frac{1}{\sinh(\pi)}.$$

Comment: Your favorite technique again. +1 the formula (functional equation) in green was given by Ramanujan without proof and is the key to obtaining such sums. Unfortunately such sums can't be handled by translating the series into elliptic integrals.

Comment: The distinguishing feature of this problem are the symmetries in the transform $Q(s)$ which were quite special to observe.

Comment: Hello Marko,
I have a question about the evaluation of the integral using the residue theorem. You state `which we evaluate by shifting it to the left for an expansion about zero` which I understand as you close the contour on the left at $-\infty$. But for that $$Q(s)x^{-s}$$ must vanish as we go to $-\infty$. But as far as I'm concerned $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)^2 \, x^{-s}$ does not vanish for any $x>0$ as we go to $-\infty$. So I would guess this is at most an asymptotic series. However what justifies this?

Comment: We are not shifting the left side to minus infinity for an asymptotic series, we just shift it to pick up all the residues and the result after shifting is seen to be a multiple of the original integral by a substitution, making for an exact formula.

Comment: Marko's result can be transformed into a simpler form. Please see the following link. https://oeis.org/A330905

Answer (score 17):

This can be derived very simply using contour integration in the complex plane.  Consider the contour integral

$$\pi \oint_C \frac{dz}{z^3 \sinh{(\pi z)} \sin{(\pi z)}} $$

where $C$ is a square centered at the origin of side $2 N+1$.  As $N \to \infty$, one may show that the contour integral approaches zero.  (Consider the magnitude of the integrand over the sides of the square.)

This means that the sum of the residues at the poles $z=\pm n$ and $z=\pm i n$ vanishes.  Note that for $n \ne 0$, the residues at $z=n$ and $z=i n$ are equal to $(-1)^n/(\pi n^3 \sinh{(\pi n)})$. 
 Also, the summand is even in $n$.  Thus we have
$$4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3 \sinh{(\pi n)}} + \operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \frac{\pi}{z^3 \sinh{(\pi z)} \sin{(\pi z)}} = 0$$

Because

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \frac{\pi}{z^3 \sinh{(\pi z)} \sin{(\pi z)}} = \frac{\pi^3}{90} $$

the stated result follows.  (NB that last residue at $z=0$ is best done using a Laurent series expansion, as the pole is of order 5.)

Comment: (+1) The chances of you providing an insightful answer through complex analysis were very high.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Glad to live up to expectations!

Answer (score 8):

I realized my original proof can be shortened by exploiting symmetry.
The first three lines are unchanged:
$$\frac{1}{\sinh z}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{z-m\pi i}+\frac{1}{z+m\pi i}\right)(-1)^m $$
$$\frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)}=\frac{1}{\pi n}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n-mi}+\frac{1}{n+mi}\right)(-1)^m $$
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\sinh(\pi n)}=\frac{\eta(4)}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{m\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+m+1}}{n^2(n^2+m^2)}$$
then by using $2\sum_{m,n\geq 1}f(m,n) = \sum_{m,n\geq 1}f(m,n)+f(n,m)$ we immediately get
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\sinh(\pi n)}=\frac{\eta(4)-\eta(2)^2}{\pi}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^3}{360}}$$
where $\eta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\,\zeta(s)$ for any $s>1$.