# A closed form for infinite series $ \sum _1 ^\infty \frac {1}{n^3} = \zeta (3) ?$

Tags: functions, zeta-functions

It is well known that $$ \sum _1 ^\infty \frac {1}{n^2} = \frac {\pi ^2}{6}$$ and $$ \sum _1 ^\infty \frac {1}{n^4} = \frac {\pi ^4}{90}$$

We also know that $$ \sum _1 ^\infty \frac {1}{n^3} $$

$$=1.202056903159594285399738161511449990764986292340498881.....$$

My question is:

Do we have a closed form for this  series  besides  $$ \sum _1 ^\infty \frac {1}{n^3}  =  \zeta (3) ?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant gives several fast converging infinite sums

Comment: Thanks, I meant something like $$\pi^? /?$$

Comment: Last time I checked, no, there is no closed form for $\zeta(n)$ where $n \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Quoting from [Establishing zeta(3) as a definite integral and its computation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30659/establishing-zeta3-as-a-definite-integral-and-its-computation/) on MO: "*it is conjectured (but not known) that the values $\zeta(2n+1)$ are ... algebraically independent of one another, and of $\pi$.*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Apéry's Constant**

As mentioned in comments
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}=\zeta(3)\tag1
$$
is also known as [Apéry's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant). There is no closed form in terms of a rational multiple of an integer power of $\pi$.

We also have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^3}=\frac78\zeta(3)\tag2
$$

However, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613341), if we alternate the series in $(2)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\tag3
$$
which is also known as $\beta(3)$, the [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

---

**Computation of $\boldsymbol{\zeta(3)}$**

The series in $(1)$ converges very slowly. To get the sum to about $10$ places, we would need to sum $100000$ terms.

If we use the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we get that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^3}=\small\zeta(3)-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{2n^3}-\frac1{4n^4}+\frac1{12n^6}-\frac1{12n^8}+\frac3{20n^{10}}-\frac5{12n^{12}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{14}}\right)\tag4
$$
Using $n=10$ in $(4)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3}=1.2020569031596\tag5
$$

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Equation (3) in particular may be of further interest.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to robojohn's answer, there are some formulas expressing $\zeta(3)$ (and other odd zeta values) in terms of powers of $\pi$, but these are not clsoed forms. The most well known ones are due to Plouffe and Borwein & Bradley:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\zeta(3)&=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)},\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\,\binom {2n}n} &= -\frac{4}{3}\,\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2\cdot 3^2}\,\left(\zeta(2, \tfrac{1}{3})-\zeta(2,\tfrac{2}{3}) \right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Moreover, in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157040/a-new-formula-for-aperys-constant-and-other-zetas) we have:

$$
\frac{3}{2}\,\zeta(3) = \frac{\pi^3}{24}\sqrt{2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3(e^{\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3(e^{2\pi k\sqrt{2}}-1)}.
$$

You can also check out [this paper by Vepstas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775v4.pdf), which provides a nice generalization to some of these identities.