# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$

Tags: summation

Probably you would have known the answer of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$ I then became curious about the reciprocal of cubes, not squares, like $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$Can you find any answer to this? I have no clue of even where to start.

Comment: It doesn't have any closed form and it is known as apery's constant

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Take a look to [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: I think that would evaluate to $1.(\text{something})$.

Comment: That's obvious @spectre

Comment: So it's a transcendental?

Comment: I think that would evaluate to 1.(something). - tried to do some guesswork - 

Comment: It is called Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(3)=1.2020...$

Comment: @Z Ahmed Thanks for the information

Comment: Apery proved it was irrational.

Comment: In case you're curious, closed forms are obtainable for $\zeta(n)$ [when $n>1$ is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers), but not when it's odd. This is related to the identity $\sin\pi z=\pi z\prod_{k\ge1}(1-z^2/k^2)$.

Comment: @ArticChar I don't agree with the current duplicate. Maybe [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019718/505767) is more appropriate.

Comment: @user I agree that the question you linked is the better target and changed the duplicate target accordingly. In similar cases, please flag for moderator attention so that the target change/addition can be done in a timely fashion.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your kind attention and intervention. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed in the comment its value is known as [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) which is related to [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), we can estimate its value by a simple integral evaluation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\approx 1+\frac18+\frac1{27}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{125}+\int_5^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}dx=\\=1+\frac18+\frac1{27}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{125}+\frac1{2\cdot 5^2}\approx 1.20566$$

which can be improved adding more terms

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\approx 1+\frac18+\frac1{27}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{125}+\ldots+\frac1{k^3}+\frac1{2k^2}$$