# reference request: Plouffe's Lambert-type series for $\zeta(2n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions, big-list, constants

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#%CE%B6(5)), Plouffe gives the series
$$\begin{align}
\zeta(5)&=\frac1{294}\pi^5-\frac{72}{35}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^5(e^{2\pi n}-1)}-\frac2{35}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^5(e^{2\pi n}+1)}\\
&=12\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^5\sinh(\pi n)}-\frac{39}{20}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^5(e^{2\pi n}-1)}-\frac1{20}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^5(e^{2\pi n}+1)},
\end{align}$$
and
$$\zeta(7)=\frac{19}{56700}\pi^7-2\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^7(e^{2\pi n}-1)}.$$
 And in general, it seems to be true that 
$$0=A_n\zeta(n)-B_n\pi^n+C_nS_-(n)+D_nS_+(n),$$
where $$S_{\pm}(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^s(e^{2\pi n}\pm 1)},$$
and $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$ are non-negative integers.

In fact, Plouffe provides [much more](http://www.lacim.uqam.ca/~plouffe/inspired22.html), but all without any links to proofs.

So, I am requesting any or all of the following:

> - Proofs of the above identities involving $\zeta(5),\zeta(7)$
> - Sources (containing proofs, sorry Ramanujan) of the theory or techniques behind Plouffe's identities in the link above
> - any other sources that you think would be relevant to this investigation.

Thank you!

Comment: Simon Plouffe used Pari-Gp to find those identities, but you might want to look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609775) paper in order to get an idea on how to prove those (sadly using complex analysis stuff).

Comment: @Zacky Why is that sad?

Comment: It should not be surprising that complex analysis is relevant to anything involving the $\zeta$ function.  As Hadamard wrote, "The shortest path between two truths on the real axis goes through the complex plane”.

Comment: Ramanujan proved a general identity for $\zeta(2n+1)$ and I think there is proof here on MSE. Will search and update with links.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38040/72031). Still searching for the proof though.

Comment: I posted a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564027/72031) which should help us out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Then Ramanujan says that $$\zeta(n) =\frac{(2\pi)^n}{2(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{(n+1)/2}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n+1}{2k}B_{n+1-2k}B_{2k}-2S_{-}(n)$$ Further one should check the easily verifiable identity $$S_{-} (n, \alpha) - S_{+} (n, \alpha) =2S_{-}(n, 2\alpha)$$ where $$S_{\pm} (n, \alpha) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n(e^{2\alpha k} \pm 1)}$$ Using these results one can verify the identities given by Plouffe. The formula for the case when $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is more complicated.

Ramanujan deals with sums of type $\sum_{k\geq 1}k^nq^k/(1-q^k)$ for odd positive integer values of $n$ in great detail with simple proofs based on algebraic manipulation. Unfortunately he does not deal with negative odd values of $n$ in same manner. I believe he did have a proof based on algebraic manipulation which was far simpler than the later proofs based on Mellin Transform.

You can also have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02964) by Bruce Berndt which gives some details and approaches to prove Ramanujan's formula. However a few key results have been provided here without proof.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment: note that Zacky's [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775.pdf) is very sloppy, p.6 for integer $m$ it is applying the residue theorem to the inverse Mellin transform integral $$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{2m+1-i\infty}^{2m+1+i\infty} \Gamma(s)\zeta(s)\zeta(s-2m+1)x^{-s}ds=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sigma_{2m-1}(n)e^{-2\pi nx}$$
Since $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-2m+1)$ vanishes at negative integers he gets that 
$$x^{2m}\sum_{n\ge 1}\sigma_{2m-1}(n)e^{-2\pi nx}$$ is a polynomial which is obviously incorrect due to the exponential decay.

> It fails because $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)\zeta(s-2m+1)$ isn't decaying as $\Re(s)\to -\infty$, in fact it is invariant under $s\to 2m-s$

For a fixed $2m$ OP's formula can be obtained from the theory of modular forms and elliptic curves with CM from which we can evaluate $E_{2m}(i),E_{2m}(2i)$ in term of $E_4(i),E_6(i)$. I don't know if there is a simple formula giving the constants for every $m$.