# Will there be a closed form expression for all $\zeta(2n+1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

It is known that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$ and that $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^{4}}{90}$. Thus, for $\zeta(2n)$, this can be generalized to :
$$
\zeta(2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}
$$
Where $B_{2n}$ are the Bernoulli's numbers. Now why is that such closed form expression does not exist for all $\zeta(2n+1)$?

Comment: It's not known whether it exists or not. It's not even known the exact value of $\zeta(3)$ for example.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/riemann-zeta-function-at-odd-positive-integers

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35412/does-zeta3-have-a-connection-with-pi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: There was an /r/math post recently about this because someone uploaded a paper to arXiv claiming new results on the sum of inverse cubes (though they were known for at least 20 years IIRC). It created a bit of hubbub from people not realizing it wasn't a real step forward in the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is an *open conjecture* whether or not $\zeta(2n+1)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2n+1}$. This not even clear for $n=1$.
The following series representation was found by Ramanujan:
$$
\zeta (3)=\frac {7}{180}\pi ^{3}-2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k^{3}(e^{2\pi k}-1)}}.
$$
His formula for $\zeta(2n+1)$ can be found [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj6udSL74vsAhXMzKQKHWpbAvYQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.math.illinois.edu%2F%7Eberndt%2Farticles%2Fzetariemann.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ifXgmDyypnLQoxaWFKvmq).

Comment: To add to this, IIRC, if $\zeta(3) = \frac{p}{q} \pi^3$, $p$ and $q$ are extremely large.

Comment: The future of mathematics looks dark.