# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2 n \pi}-1)}$

Tags: summation, infinite-product, theta-functions, ramanujan-summation, elliptic-modular-form

I need to calculate the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2 n \pi}-1)}$$

Write $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2 n \pi}-1)}$$
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{-2 \pi n m}$$
Now changing the order of summation $$S=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-2 \pi n m}}{n}$$$$S=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \log(1-e^{-2\pi m})$$
So $$S=\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi n}}\right)$$
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See $a(q^2)$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. Any simpler proof please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last expression is in fact $\;\displaystyle S=-\log \phi\left(e^{-2\pi}\right)\,$ with $\phi$ the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) $\;\displaystyle \phi(q):=\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1-q^n$.

Fortunately [Ramanujan found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function#Special_values) that $\;\displaystyle \phi\left(e^{-2\pi}\right)=\frac {e^{\,\pi/12}\,\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)}{2\pi^{3/4}}\,$
(proof by Bruce Berndt in page $326$ of [Ramanujan's Notebooks Part V](https://books.google.com/books?id=O8XcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA326#v=onepage&q&f=false) )

allowing us some simplification of Paramanand Singh's powerful general answer :

$$\boxed{S=\log(2)+\frac 34\log(\pi)-\frac {\pi}{12}-\log\left(\Gamma\left(\frac 14\right)\right)}$$

Comment: +1. Thanks. Can we express another sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2 \pi n}-1)}$ in terms of an infinite product of logarithm?

Comment: @Max: put $n=1$ in the Ramanujan Grosswald formula given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38040/72031) to get the sum $\sum n^{-3}/(e^{2\pi n} - 1)$.

Comment: I got (experimental math) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2 n \pi}-1)}=\frac 7{360}\pi^3-\frac 12\zeta(3)\,$ for comparison. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped @Max and excellent continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Simon Plouffe and Joerg Arndt found (also via experimental math) the case $p=3,7,11,$ etc in a 1998 paper. Kindly see second answer.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: The general answer for $\zeta(2n+1)$ for odd positive integer $n$ was in fact linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35412/does-zeta3-have-a-connection-with-pi/38040#38040) by Paramanand Singh. Your more direct expression is welcome (and was upvoted!) anyway. Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I was so sleepy that I missed the word "***odd n***", hence the concise formula in Singh's link dealt with $\zeta(4m+3)$. I've added Plouffe and Arndt's formulas for $\zeta(4m+1)$. Do you know if its concise general formula exists somewhere in MSE?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I don't know sorry. I played with these things around $2001$ starting with Plouffe's "inspired guesses". Combining the two series by Ramanujan shows that $\displaystyle \pi=6\left(\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)}+\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}+1)}\right)+\frac 92 \log 2$. Pleasant days anyway... :-)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni ah, the case $p =1$. Thanks! May add it later for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

(*More an extended comment but links to the general case*.) Just in case the OP is curious about other exponents $p$, I asked a variation of it in a [2012 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157040/4781) which was based on Simon Plouffe's [1998 paper](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/articles/Identities.pdf), "*Identities Inspired from Ramanujan’s Notebooks*". For the special case $p=4m+3$, Plouffe and later Joerg Arndt found,

$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\frac{7}{360}\pi^3-\frac12\zeta(3)$$
$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^7(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\frac{19}{113400}\pi^7-\frac12\zeta(7)$$
$$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{11}(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\frac{1453}{851350500}\pi^{11}-\frac12\zeta(11)$$

and so on. The general formula for $\zeta(2n+1)$ with odd $\color{red}n$, hence $\zeta(4m+3)$, can be found in [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38040/4781) linked by both Singh and Manzoni.

However, the OP's exponent uses the form $p = 4m+1$ so has different results, namely,

$$\log(2) = -\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)} -\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}+1)}+\frac{2}{9}\pi$$

$$\zeta(5) = -\frac{72}{35}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5(e^{2\pi n}-1)} -\frac{2}{35}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5(e^{2\pi n}+1)}+\frac{1}{294}\pi^5$$

$$\zeta(9) = -\frac{992}{495}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9(e^{2\pi n}-1)} -\frac{2}{495}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9(e^{2\pi n}+1)}+\frac{125}{3704778}\pi^9$$

with the last two by Plouffe and Arndt, and so on.  Presumably, there should also be a concise general formula for $\zeta(4m+1)$.

---

**Note 1:** In the [2012 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157040/4781) I cited, Marko Riedel uses a general approach that handles both $p=4m\pm1$, but didn't give an explicit formula.

**Note 2:** Combining known results for $p=1$, we have the nice,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)} &=+\frac {3\log(\pi)}4-\log\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac 14\big)\Big)-\frac {\pi}{12}+\log(2)\\
\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}+1)} &=-\frac{ 3\log(\pi)}4+\log\Big(\Gamma\big(\tfrac 14\big)\Big)\,+\,\frac {\pi}{4}-\frac{7\log(2)}4
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Thank you so much

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the formulas for $\zeta(4m+1)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: We can use your result and Manzoni's result to have a closed-form for the positive case of $p=1$ as well. See Note 2 above.

Comment: @Max When $p$ is _negative_, for example $p=-3$, then we have $$\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{e^{2\pi n}-1}$$ which has closed-forms too, and again depending on whether $p = 4m\pm1.$ Singh helped with the answer. Kindly checked [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1943244/4781).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I just asked a question about $\zeta(4m+1)$. Kindly check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757836/4781).

Answer (score 1):

Tito Piezas III added (not long ago...) :
$$\zeta(5) = -\frac{72}{35}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5(e^{2\pi n}-1)} -\frac{2}{35}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5(e^{2\pi n}+1)}+\frac{1}{294}\pi^5$$

$$\zeta(9) = -\frac{992}{495}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9(e^{2\pi n}-1)} -\frac{2}{495}\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9(e^{2\pi n}+1)}+\frac{125}{3704778}\pi^9$$

"Presumably, there should also be a concise general formula for $\zeta(4+1)$."

From this challenge (and the next solutions up to $4m+1=49$) I'll conjecture a general formula for $m>0$ :

$$\zeta(4m+1)-q_{4m+1}\,\pi^{4m+1}=\frac {-2}{2^{2m}\left(2^{2m+1}-(-1)^m\right)-1}\left(2^{2m}\left(2^{2m+1}-(-1)^m\right)\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4m+1}(e^{2\pi n}-1)}+\sum_{n= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4m+1}(e^{2\pi n}+1)}\right)$$
I didn't get an expression for $\,q_m\in\mathbb{Q}\,$ yet but would conjecture that it could be similar to the Bernoulli sums from this  [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38040/21783).

*ADDITION:*
Following expression for $\zeta(4m+1)$ was indeed provided by Linas Vepstas in ["On Plouffe's Ramanujan Identities"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609775) (from Zander's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157998/21783)) :
\begin{align}&\left(1+(-4)^{m}-2^{4m+1}\right)\zeta(4m+1)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{4m+1}\left(e^{2\pi n}+1\right)}+2\left(2^{4m+1}-(-4)^{m}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{4m+1}\left(e^{2\pi n}-1\right)}\\
&+(2\pi)^{4m+1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-4)^{m+j}\frac{B_{4m-4j+2}}{(4m-4j+2)!}\frac{B_{4j}}{(4j)!}+\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}\frac{(-4)^{j}}2\frac{B_{4m-2j+2}}{(4m-2j+2)!}\frac{B_{2j}}{(2j)!}\right)
\end{align}

Mathworld contains the first odd zeta expressions with $\displaystyle S_{\pm}(n):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n(e^{2 \pi k}\pm 1)}$ :
\begin{align}
\zeta(3)&=\frac 7{180}\pi^3 - 2S_-(3)\\
\zeta(5)&=\frac 1{294}\pi^5 -\frac {72}{35} S_-(5)-\frac 2{35}S_+(5)\\
\zeta(7)&=\frac {19}{56700}\pi^7 - 2S_-(7)\\
\zeta(9)&=\frac {125}{3704778}\pi^9 -\frac {992}{495} S_-(9)-\frac 2{495}S_+(9)\\
\zeta(11)&=\frac {1453}{425675250}\pi^{11} - 2S_-(11)\\
\zeta(13)&=\frac {89}{257432175}\pi^{13} -\frac {16512}{8255} S_-(13)-\frac 2{8255}S_+(13)\\
\end{align}

To emphasize the similarities between these lines let's observe :

- the $\zeta(4m+1)$ terms could be rewritten as $\displaystyle -2S_-(4m+1)+\frac 2{1+(-4)^{m}-2^{4m+1}}\left(S_-(4m+1)+S_+(4m+1)\right)$
- the ratios $\zeta(2m+1)$ divided by $q_{2m+1}\;\pi^{2m+1}$ converge quickly to $\;\tanh(\pi)\approx 0.99627207622$

Comment: I just separated the question for $\zeta(4m+1)$. Kindly have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757836/4781)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Vepstas provided the general formula in his 2006 paper! $q_{2m+1}\;\pi^{2m+1}$ is the main term, the $S_-$ a correction, $S_-+S_+$ a fluctuation and a further one with $(-4)^m$ !